# Issues with database in Razor website Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio, razor, webmatrix

I am building a new Razor (WebMatrix) website in Visual Studio and have done it before but it's just not working this time.

It keeps throwing this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

I've seen a few of these problems here on SO questions and the solution seems to be to add reference to System.Data or WebMatrix.Data and it just isn't working for me.

In the `bin` folder, there is no `System.Data.dll` but when I try to add as reference I get "Is already included in project" error - but it isn't in the folder.

But - I have also tried @using System.Data along with @using WebMatrix.Data; and it still won't work.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: To be sure if the dll exists, check in References folder, select the file and in property window check path, check for the file in the path.

Comment: What operating system an VS version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to your project references, right clicking on System.Data or WebMatrix.Data, clicking properties and setting Copy Local to true?